# Namespace for WebBrowser aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, namespaces

I am having problems figuring out which namespace the WebBrowser datatype belongs to. these are my following asp imports.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Windows" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Windows.Forms" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Services.Protocols" %>
```

Am I doing something wrong? I would like to use the WebBrowser datatype.

Thank you

I am trying to do this but just in an aspx page.

```
dynamic document = webBrowser.Document;
document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is

`System.Windows.Forms`

which contains the WebBrowser.

From MSDN : [`WebBrowser Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)

> Enables the user to navigate Web pages inside your form.

**EDIT:**

Replace This:

```
dynamic document = webBroweser.Document;
```

With This:

```
WebBrowser webbrowser1 - new WebBrowser();
dynamic document = webbrowser1.Document;
```

Comment: I have that in my namespace imports but my aspx page doesnt hint me for WebBrowser when i write it in.

Comment: I have fixed the typo. it still doesnt hint me with the datatype

Comment: @user3214892: you need to have webbrowser instance variable, check my edited answer

Comment: I can not create the webbrowser instance variable. my aspx page wont hint for it at all